# What is an Account Manager and why would an agency have me speak with one before hiring?

Tags: interviewing, recruitment, tech-industry

I’m a bit new to this having been out of school for a few years, so I may have some misunderstandings. About 6 months ago I was in contact with a tech recruiting agency. One day while I was at my current job I received several calls and messages from the contact to start a new (allegedly better) job the next day. My contact insisted I speak with an Account Manager. I emphasised this wasn’t a good time to speak but they said it was urgent and only would take a few minutes. I also told the account manager it was an inconvenient time and asked if I could call when I’m done work but she insisted. After 30 minutes on the call I must have lost my patients and was rude. After that my contacts at the agency stopped responding.

Just last week a different recruiter from the same agency contacted me. I asked her why the agency abruptly stopped contact with me (I had a relationship with them, such as writing a proficiency test and was under the impression I was on the list for multiple positions). She said she would look into it and latter I got an email saying that the account manager found me abrasive. She also looked bad that I said I don’t know the details of the job…which is true because the recruiter just called me about it and I had no chance to research it. I explained to her my side of the story and she says she would work with me and explain to me how things work.

Does this seem like a good agency to work with or are they just playing games? I know some agencies are good but I also have had the experience where they just waste time.

What is an account manager? Why would I have to talk to them and what is their role? Are they the ones deciding if I get hired or not? Who do they work for? Also, should I just chalk it up to unusual circumstances that they were asking me to quit my current job with no notice, or should I ask for an explanation before continuing with them? I mean I’m a bit skeptical being hired without an in person interview (provided the work was in the same city).

Answer (score 1):

Many times the account manager will like to figure out how to sell a person or if they are not going to be a good fit for a job.  It is part of their process.  Some companies take it more seriously than others.

The recruiter is the person responsible to you the consultant.  The Account manager is the person responsible to the client for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking to anyone on the phone about a job, assume it's an interview. Your chat with the account manager was an interview, and you failed it.

I know it sucks, and i agree they were being unreasonable in not offering to reschedule. But always know the game you're playing, in which you appear to be the bright, hardworking, professional and accommodating applicant, and they play the role of important interviewer.

They may be shady or not - who knows. But don't worry about it too much. There are plenty of recruiting agencies out there, abd they should allow for at least two weeks' notice.